# How is rate of change dx/dt in ladder problem doesn't match the actual rate of change.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, applications, implicit-differentiation

[image: Part 2]
[image: Question]

The pictures above describes the question. We have to find the rate of change in x-axis direction.

The answer is derived from implicit differentiation and is $4/3$. The process is: [y(t) gives y-axis length (red line) and x(t) gives x-axis length (green line) where t is seconds after initial picture]

$$
\begin{align}
&(y(t))^2 + (x(t))^2 &= 5^2 \\
&\implies \frac {d[(y(t))^2 + (x(t))^2]} {dt} &= \frac{d25} {dt} \\
&\implies \frac {2y\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + 2x\frac{dx(t)}{dt}} {dt} &= 0 \\
&\implies {2y\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + 2x\frac{dx(t)}{dt}} &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

At $t=0$,

$$
\begin{align}
&{2(4)(-1) + 2(3)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}} &= 0 \\
&\implies -8+6\frac{dx(t)}{dt} &= 0 \\
&\implies \frac{dx(t)}{dt} &= \frac 86 \\
&\implies \frac{dx(t)}{dt} &= \frac 43 \\
\end{align}
$$

But by solving intuitionally: $y(t)$ becomes 0 after $4/1 = 4$ seconds so the $x(t) = 5$ when $t = 4$. Since the rate of change is constant then we can calculate rate of change as change in $x(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=4$ divided by $4-0=4$

$$
\text{Rate of change = } = \frac {5-3} {4} = \frac 2 4 = \frac 12
$$

This contradicts above result. So which one is correct and why?

One possible answer I thought could be that the rate of change of $x(t)$ is not constant as $y(t)$ is. So is that it?

Comment: Why do you think he rate of change of y  or x  is constant?

Comment: because isn't question tells us that rate of change of y is constant with $-1$

Comment: @PrabhasKumar: but then your equations show that $$ x'=\frac yx,$$ clearly not constant.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I also saw that so the rate of change x is infact not constant?

Comment: It is only -1 when t =0.

Comment: @Paul oh. So the rate of change of x is y/x at that time. I understand now

Comment: You should try standing on a sliding ladder. You hit the ground very much faster than when you start sliding!

Comment: @Paul No thanks. I'll take your word for it.